# style host in Angular from component

Tags: angular

You can style the component host in .css file using `:host` selector. I'd like to set the `top` on the component host from the component.

For example, given `<app-test> </app-test>`,  I'd like to dynamically style host of AppTestComponent from the component itself.

Is this possible in Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to dynamically style the component itself. First, you will need to inject `ElementRef` as a dependency. Then you can access the host via `this._elementRef.nativeElement`.

```js
@Component({
  //...
})
export class AppTestComponent {

  constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef) {

    this._elementRef.nativeElement.style.color = 'red';
  }
}
```

### BUT, this is not recommended.

First of all, it's possibly a [security risks](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef#:%7E:text=Permitting%20direct%20access%20to%20the%20DOM%20can%20make%20your%20application%20more%20vulnerable%20to%20XSS%20attacks.%20Carefully%20review%20any%20use%20of%20ElementRef%20in%20your%20code.) according to Angular.

It is best to have an `@Input` class/style that let the parent passes into `app-test`. This way, the `app-test` doesn't have to worry about the environment around it, and does more than it needs to.